# to pickup or be picked up

Tags: word-choice

Is it better to say:

> "something is available for pickup in my office"

or

> "something is available to be picked up in my office"?

Also is **pickup** one word or two in the above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I think they're both equally acceptable.  One of the definitions of *pickup* is:

> an act of collecting a person or goods, esp. in a vehicle

I think *for pickup* is more common in colloquial English, *to be picked up* is more wordy and sounds more formal.

When used as a noun or adjective, it's a single, compound word. When used as a verb, it's split into the original two words: *pick up your clothes.*

Comment: Thanks, Barmar.  That really helped.  I am going with the first because it looks cleaner.